# Split PHP page over 2 domains - send variables to 2nd domain and back again

Tags: php, variables, post, get

I need to split a php page between two domains. That is, I need to send some variables (including arrays) to a second domain, where some calculations will be done using the variables, then I need to get the results back to the first domain.

Currently I have one php page that takes some variables, does calculations on them and shows the results. I want to share this functionality with owners of other domains while keeping secret how the calculations are done.

I think the best way to do this is to give them a php page that sends the variables to my domain, where the calculations are done, and then send the results back.

I am wondering what the best way to do this will be. I would appreciate a point in the right direction if anyone has done something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the sites using your data are going to be displaying it inline there, this sort of functionality would typically be done with AJAX. Make a page that accepts the variables, performs the calculations, and then outputs the results as JSON. The sites requiring calculations will simply POST their values to your page and capture the results, which are easily parsed in any language.

Comment: That's a rather presumptuous statement, don't you think?

Comment: I disagree. He's saying that he doesn't want the client to know the algorithm -- not that he doesn't want the clients to know that there's work being done.

Comment: Yeah that's how I read it. (Is it correct? I dunno... hopefully the OP will answer that for us.)

Comment: Yes, the client will know work is done on my server/site. I want to hide the algorithm only.

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of data to be transmitted isn't to big, I'd use a `urlencode` setup:

PHP 1:

```
$a=urlencode(serialize($array1));
$b=urlencode($value2);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/getvalue.php?a='.$a.'&b='.$b);
```

PHP2:

```
$array1:=unserialize(urldecode($_GET['a']));
$value2=urldecode($b);
//Now do your calculations
echo $result;
```

But it depends on your data if that really is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it, but the data being sent over from the client (from PHP 1 in your example) can be a lot, the result being sent back won't be much.

Comment: server to server is used in a lot of e-com sites, works well. can use web services too. this would work great too, even if a big text file was being sent